# Dynamically load the log4j jar and properties file at runtime and use the Logger instance to log

Tags: java, log4j

I have a situation -

1. log4j jar is not available at classpath and it is needs to be loaded from a file path at runtime.
2. Then need to create the Logger instance and log into a file. log4j.properties also needs to be loaded at runtime.

Comment: I have tried to use URLClassLoader to load the jar but not able to create the Logger instance out of it as I have limited experience in reflection

Comment: 1. Doesn't make any sense. You don't load jars from files.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115900/is-it-possible-to-reload-log4j-xml-log4j-properties-file-dynamically-in-tomcat

Comment: I have tried with - 
File myJar = new File("C:\\log4jjar\\log4j.jar");
URL url = myJar.toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url }, System.class.getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName("org.apache.log4j.Logger", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("getLogger",String.class);
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
Object result = method.invoke(instance);
--- But classToLoad.newInstance() giving me exception as Logger dies not have no arg constructor. So how to create the instance?

Comment: You didn't get my comment. There can be no reason, none whatsoever, to load a log4j.jar at runtime. Leave it on classpath in your build file from the beginning. As for programmatically configuring Log4J, Google it, there are many references.