# How can you configure Kafka server logging so that you can change log levels without a restart?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka

At INFO level logging, with the load we are putting on the server, Kafka is logging more than 8,000 lines per minute.  I am thinking to set the log level to WARN for normal runtime, but would like to be able to modify the log level back to INFO without requiring a restart.  Is there a logging configuration that Kafka supports which will do this?

A little more background:  The default setup of Kafka (from the tarball download), uses log4j1 which does not requires specific code setup (configureAndWatch) to track settings to the config file.  I saw that Kafka enables plugging in other frameworks via SLF4J, but I have no idea if that will solve this problem.

Comment: This is really a log4j question ("How to I change log4j levels at runtime") and unrelated to Kafka.

Comment: Removed Kafka specifics from question

Comment: Also, you're welcome to split the log cleaner logs to a separate file, but those messages are actually very useful, even at info level... It tells you that the topics are being truncated. If that logcleaner thread stops, your disks fill up and Kafka dies

Comment: @cricket_007: thanks for edits. I'm not sure this is a log4j 1 question.  AFAIK, you can only *programmatically* set log4j 1 to dynamically reload settings, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115900/is-it-possible-to-reload-log4j-xml-log4j-properties-file-dynamically-in-tomcat).  (All our log4j1  applications are coded to `configureAndWatch`.)  So I was looking for a way to do this in Kafka without modifying the server source code.  Alternatively, I believe Kafka supports plugging in other log frameworks through SLF4J, but I was hoping to use the out of the box setup.

Comment: I know at least logback and lof4j2 supports doing so via JMX. Maybe one day I'll get around to actually contributing and officially getting rid of log4j 1.x